# A question regarding the prime-counting function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

We know that the prime-counting function, $\pi(x)$, can be written as:
$$
\pi(x)=\sum_{p\;prime} 1
$$
Now, one way to rewrite this is that if you consider that the function $a(x)$ represents whether $x$ is prime or not, such that:
$$
a(x)=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if x is prime} \\
0, & \text{if otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
And now, we can rewrite $\pi(x)$ as:
$$
\pi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^x a(n)
$$
Now, if you let $\delta(x)$ be a function that is similar to $\pi(x)$, but not exactly, such that:
$$
\delta(x)=\sum_{n=1}^x a(n)a(x-n)
$$
Can we write $\delta(x)$ in terms of $\pi(x)$?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems unlikely that $\delta(x)$ can be written in terms of $\pi(x)$ in any meaningful capacity.

Note that $a(n)a(x-n)=1$ if and only if $n$ and $x-n$ are prime (and it's $0$ otherwise). So, $\delta(x)$ counts the number of (ordered) pairs of prime numbers that sum to $x$. In particular, it is open (Goldbach's conjecture) whether $\delta(2m)>0$ for all positive integers $m\geq 4$.

Comment: Actually I believe you can, since the summation $\sum_{i=1}^f a_ib_i$ can be broken into $(\sum_{i=1}^f a_i)(\sum_{i=1}^f b_i) - \sum_{i=1}^f [a_i\sum_{j=1\;j \neq i}^f b_j]$.

Comment: @Tots01 I've updated my answer.